# Finding the region of convergence of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have the following  series, with a and b being real parameters:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{a^n+b^n}$$ with $0<a<b$. My complex analysis is really rusty, and any hints and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Finding radius of convergence is just using Hadamard's formula, which is not complex analysis. I suggest you look up the formula and try to evaluate the limit yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\sqrt[n]{\frac1{a^n+b^n}}=\frac1{\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}}=\frac1{b\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac ab\right)^n+1}},$$we have$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{a^n+b^n}}=\frac1b$$and therefore the radius of convergence is $\frac1{1/b}=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when $n$ is large, $a^n/b^n$ is close to $0$.